# Is there a JGit equivalent to "git add -f"?

Tags: git, jgit

I'm looking for a way to force add files in jgit, even if they are contained in the gitignore. Is there a method for this?

Comment: AFAIK, force-adding is not supported by JGit's `AddCommand`, the equivalent of `git add`. Given it's just ~300 lines of code, I would make a copy and adjust the condition that evaluates `WorkingTreeIterator::isEntryIgnored` (currently around line 170)

Comment: You can also report the request/patch at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ to get the feature added in a future version.